Can I still use the save files on my SD Card of my broken 2DS?
I have a broken 2DS that won’t turn on at all, won’t even charge. I’ve opened it up and everything looks fine and I’ve tried so many things but nothing helps.
I simply just want back the games that I have on the SD card that I bought through the eshop, like Animal Crossing New Leaf, Fire Emblem Awakening, etc.
Since these games were bought off the eshop, and the eshop has closed, is there any way for me to use those save files on a new 2DS or 3DS if I buy one? Would it be as easy as putting my SD card into a new 2DS, or would I not have the same save files from those games that I had on my original 2DS?
OR are there any handheld emulators that I could put those save files onto?

Do you have a card reader for the sd card? You could check if the sd card itself is still functioning and has data on it and make a backup before you do anything.
